# Why is “Jung” translated 荣格?

Tags: translation

I feel like this might be another “Holmes”-type translation.

How did “Jung” as in Carl Gustav Jung get translated as 荣格?

I can’t hear the transliteration at all, myself.

How did it turn out to be translated this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carl Jung was Swiss German. Jung is pronounced /jʊŋ/ (IPA), so I'd say 荣格 is pretty close, and a perfectly acceptable transliteration.

Comment: The Chinese r- sound does not sound like /j/ at all to me -_-

Answer (score 0):

荣格 is sounded like rongger.I think it is just try to seperate from the transkation of zhang which is translated as 张 in chinese